# Server recieving empty POST http request body from c client

Tags: php, c, http, post

I'm trying to submit a form from a c client using raw HTTP and sockets, here is the plain http Post request:

```
POST /demo/handle_form.php HTTP/1.0\r\n
Host:127.0.0.1\r\n
Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Content-Length:%d\r\n
\r\n
name=arsh&password=32ewew\r\n
```

**content-length is set to 26 in this case**

and the response I get:

```
Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 01 Aug 2022 17:05:29 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1o PHP/8.1.6 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
X-Powered-By: PHP/8.1.6
Content-Length: 334
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <h1>Succesfully recieved</h1> 
       <p></p>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see that the p tag is empty while it must shows the `name` parameter.

I'm running php on xampp server and it's functioning since it works just fine when sending request from other clients such as postman, curl, ...

The C code client:

```
#include <stdio.h> /* printf, sprintf */
#include <stdlib.h> /* exit */
#include <unistd.h> /* read, write, close */
#include <string.h> /* memcpy, memset */
#include <sys/socket.h> /* socket, connect */
#include <netinet/in.h> /* struct sockaddr_in, struct sockaddr */
#include <netdb.h> /* struct hostent, gethostbyname */

void error(const char *msg) { perror(msg); exit(0); }
size_t calculate_length(char* s1, char *s2, char *s3);


// size_t calculate_length(char* s1, char *s2, char *s3) {

//     return strlen(s1) + strlen(s2) + strlen(s3);

// }

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    /* first what are we going to send and where are we going to send it? */
    char *message_fmt = "POST /demo/handle_form.php HTTP/1.0\r\nHost:127.0.0.1\r\nContent-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length:%d\r\n\r\nname=arsh&password=32ewew\r\n";
    int portno =        80;
    char *host =        "127.0.0.1";

    struct hostent *server;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int sockfd, bytes, sent, received, total, content_length;
    char message[1024],response[4096];

    // if (argc < 3) { puts("Parameters: <apikey> <command>"); exit(0); }
    content_length = 25;
    /* fill in the parameters */
    sprintf(message,message_fmt,content_length);
    printf("Request:\n%s\n",message);

    /* create the socket */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

    /* lookup the ip address */
    server = gethostbyname(host);
    if (server == NULL) error("ERROR, no such host");

    /* fill in the structure */
    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    memcpy(&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,server->h_addr,server->h_length);

    /* connect the socket */
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
        error("ERROR connecting");

    // /* send the request */
    send(sockfd, message, strlen(message)+content_length, 0);
    /* receive the response */
    memset(response,0,sizeof(response));
    total = sizeof(response)-1;
    received = 0;
    do {
        bytes = read(sockfd,response+received,total-received);
        if (bytes < 0)
            error("ERROR reading response from socket");
        if (bytes == 0)
            break;
        received+=bytes;
    } while (received < total);

    /*
     * if the number of received bytes is the total size of the
     * array then we have run out of space to store the response
     * and it hasn't all arrived yet - so that's a bad thing
     */
    if (received == total)
        error("ERROR storing complete response from socket");

    /* close the socket */
    close(sockfd);

    /* process response */
    printf("Response:\n%s\n",response);

    return 0;
}
```

the problem:
BUT SOMEHOW THE BODY IS NOT FINDING IT'S WAY THROUGH THE SERVER AND I CAN'T FIGURE IT OUT.

the php server just in case:

```
<?php  

        $f = fopen("data.txt", "a");
        $username = $_POST["name"];
        $password = $_POST["password"];

        fwrite($f, $username."  ". $password);
        fwrite($f, PHP_EOL);
        fclose($f);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
       <h1>Succesfully recieved</h1> 
       <p><?php print($_POST["name"]);?></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think I'd inspect `$_SERVER` to see if something funky is in there by doing `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: what should I exactly look for in the output?

Comment: First, that the method is in fact `POST`, and honestly just looking for weirdness. You should be able to make a very simple HTML page that also POSTS to this page to compare against, too.

Comment: You make no checks at all... is the file "data.txt" created? Are there spaces in there and newlines? Dump all Superglobals, plus `file_get_contents('php://input')` aka the raw input. Check the error logs as well.

Comment: `Content-Type:x-www-form-urlencoded` is wrong, it is actually `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: `content-length is set to 26 in this case` - doesn't seem right either. `name=arsh&password=32ewew` would be 25, but with the additional `\r\n` at the end, it should be 27.

Comment: @CBroe You just solved it dude, god bless you